# htaccess category seo url redirecting to 404 page in localhost

Tags: seo, htaccess, php, wampserver

I am trying to edit my htaccess.

All urls working fine on server, but same htaccess setup redirecting
category/cat_name/ url to 404 page without giving any error. all other
urls working fine accept category url.

I setup my links without an id and searching urls with seo_url wich is
added to database, I have checked all urls in database one by one they
looks fine. Looks like problem is in my htaccess I have tried several
regex typo and `[L,QSA]` variables too but didnt change anything. I am
using wamp server and php version 7.3.0 on localhost, `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

I have read same questions on community sites and searched on google before asking this question none solved my problem.

My `.htaccess` is in root of the site

Url on browser looks fine:
http://localhost/site/category/services/

My php link example :

```
href="category/<?php echo $row['seo_url'];?>/" title="<?php echo $row['cat_name'];?>">
```

My htaccess url :

```
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ categories.php?q=$1 [L,NC]
```

My codes in my categories.php

```
if(isset($_GET["q"])){
    $seourl = htmlspecialchars($_GET["q"]);
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE seo_url=:seo_url");
    $stmt->execute(array(':seo_url'=>$seourl));
    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $ctid = intval($row['cat_id']);
            $ctname = htmlspecialchars($row['cat_name']);
            $ctseo_url = htmlspecialchars($row['seo_url']);
            $descriptions = htmlspecialchars($row['descriptions']);
            $keywords = htmlspecialchars($row['keywords']);
            $created = htmlspecialchars($row['created']);
            $img = htmlspecialchars($row['img']);
    }else{
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Category not exist";    
        header("location: ../error.php");
        exit();
        }
}else{
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Category not exist";    
        header("location: ../error.php");
        exit();
    }
```

As you can see in code I search url with `seo_url` which is added to
database, if there something wrong with url it should redirect me to
error.php, but its redirecting to 404 page without giving an error.

all links htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ detail.php?p=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ categories.php?q=$1 [L,NC] 
RewriteRule ^contact/$ contact.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^forgot/$ hml.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^search/$ search.php [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^services/$ keywords.php?q=%1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^kariyer-basvuru/ ik.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^feed/$ rss.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^cat-feed/$ feed.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^user/$ login.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^change-password/$ resetpass.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^Upanel/page/(.*)$ Upanel/?page=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^Upanel/page_sale/(.*)/$ Upanel/account.php?page_sale=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^Upanel/del-ilan/(.*)/$ Upanel/delil.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^Upanel/Store-edit/(.*)/$ Upanel/Sedit.php?store_id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^Upanel/del-store/(.*)/$ Upanel/Sdel.php?store_id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^Upanel/del-comment/(.*)/$ Upanel/Cdel.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^Upanel/opens/$ Upanel/opens.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^Upanel/editadds/(.*)/$ Upanel/Pedit.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^Upanel/ilanv/$ Upanel/ilanv.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^Upanel/profil-duzenle/(.*)/$ Upanel/profile.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^Upanel/$ Upanel/index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^stores/(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ store.php?s=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^stores/$ isletmeler.php [L,NC]
ErrorDocument 404 404.shtml
```

Comment: Where _on the filesystem_ is your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: in root (site).

Comment: So, the `.htaccess` file is located at `/site/.htaccess`. This may be the site-root, but it's not the document root. Is this how it's configured on the live site? `../error.php` would then imply `error.php` is above the site-root? Do you have anything else in your `.htaccess` file? Have you confirmed that `categories.php` is not being called?

Comment: no its not configured like that, on live server .htaccess is in root of the site which is `www` but I don't think its a problem if you check htaccess in question is setup to work in any folder its in. I am using `<base>` tag to tell htaccess main url. and all other urls works fine is well. looks like htaccess doesnt call categories.php, my full htaccess is in question.

Comment: Your `.htaccess` _looks OK_. Are you sure `categories.php` is not being called, just without a URL parameter? You are not seeing any redirection in the browser? (If this is all in the document root on the live site, then a redirect like `../error.php` would seem to be a problem on the live site - unless you are compensating with the `base` tag?)

Comment: this is all in original htaccess on server with  www and https redirecting codes in, `base tag` in local is setup like: `http://localhost/site/` and .htaccess is in `/site/` this is my php url `href="category/<?php echo $row['seo_url'];?>/" title="<?php echo $row['cat_name'];?>">` and this is url in `.htaccess` `RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ categories.php?q=$1 [L,NC]`  I don't know how to check if categories.php is called or not. what I see htaccess should call it and redirect to error.php instead of rendering 404 page. if something wrong wit url.

Comment: Try adding `Options -MultiViews` at the top of your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I did try -multiiews `<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>` then category links works but redirecting other urls like (/contact/, /login/, /register/) to error.php even there isnt a code to redirect to error.php in that pages . when I check with `categories.php?q=seo_url` it works fine. so there is something wrong going on in exist htaccess codes, it doesnt call to categories.php.

Comment: Please include your file structure. Do you have any other `.htaccess` files (in subdirectories)?

Comment: Thanks for your effort bro it works fine know, I added solution to question. thanks again I couldn't solve the problem without your advice. I am surprised how it works fine on server but doesnt work in local. Thanks again

Comment: Glad you got it working. You can add your solution as an "answer" (and later accept it) - otherwise the question stays in the unanswered question queue. The solution is "odd" - although differences in `MultiViews` and query string parameters can be the result of different server configs. However, setting `Options -MultiViews` at the top should be no different. You should also be able to do this in one line: `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews`. Differences in server modules (typically mod_security) can interfere with query string parameters - although that doesn't look to be the case here?

Comment: I wasn't deleted my cokkies when I added it on the top of the `.htacccess` might be because of that it mixed up other urls, I didnt know I can answer my own question will do it know. thanks

Comment: If `MultiViews` is enabled then it can result in a request for `categories` being internally rewritten to `categories.php` (without a query string) before mod_rewrite is able to process the URL. But you are requesting `category`, not `categories` - so it's not clear why that would have been a problem here. Existing file/directories can also play a part (with mod_negotiation conflicts).

Comment: I'm closing this question because you indicate it was solved in the comments without getting an answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work thanks adding solution if someone need it:
I added `MultiViews` under `FollowSymLinks` it doesn't work on the top of the `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
```

I changed search term `q` to `c`, it shouldn't make a difference but it does, I don't understand why anyone with knowledge can explain beter.lol.

```
categories.php?c=$1
```